# map() method from mocked ModelMapper returns null value

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, modelmapper

i'm struggling with some weird problem related with Mockito and JUnit 5 with Spring Boot application.

Here is the fragment of my `AccountServiceTest` class:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@Import(MapperConfig.class)
class AccountServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Mock
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Mock
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Mock
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Mock
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @InjectMocks
    private AccountService underTest;

    @Test
    void itShouldCreateAccountAndAddItToDatabase() {
        // given
        CreateAccountDto dto = new CreateAccountDto("service.tester@test.com", "service.tester", "12345");

        // when
        Account account = underTest.create(dto);
        Account found = accountRepository.findByUsername(account.getUsername()).orElseThrow();

        // then
        assertEquals(found, account);
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is the service I want to test:

```java
@Service
public class AccountService implements FieldValueExists {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    public Account create(CreateAccountDto dto) {
        Account account = modelMapper.map(dto, Account.class);
        account.setHashedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(dto.getPassword()));

        accountRepository.save(account);

        return account;
    }
    ...
}
```

Everything seems to work in the `AccountService` itself when used in the controller, but in the testing unit the `modelMapper.map(...)` method returns null object, so it throws an infamous `NullPointerException`.

Also I've managed to put a Configuration for this mapper in `MapperConfig`:

```java
@Configuration
public class MapperConfig {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

        /*
          Account's related mappings
         */
        modelMapper
                .typeMap(CreateAccountDto.class, Account.class);

        modelMapper
                .typeMap(Account.class, AccountDto.class);

        modelMapper
                .typeMap(Account.class, AuthorDto.class);

        /*
          Note's related mappings
         */
        modelMapper
                .typeMap(CreateNoteDto.class, Note.class);

        modelMapper
                .typeMap(Note.class, NoteDto.class);

        modelMapper
                .typeMap(EditNoteDto.class, Note.class)
                .addMappings(mapper -> {
                    mapper.when(ctx -> ctx.getSource() != null).map(EditNoteDto::getTitle, Note::setTitle);
                    mapper.when(ctx -> ctx.getSource() != null).map(EditNoteDto::getContent, Note::setContent);
                });


        return modelMapper;
    }
}
```

I don't know what is going wrong, since the dependencies in `AccountServiceTest` are mocked correctly, I think.

Comment: It is not enough to just inject the mocks, we have to also configure the mocks. I recommend reading a tutorial on mockito, e.g. [this one from `baeldung.com`](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-series).

Comment: Do you mean that every mock must define what every method should do in my testing unit? If not, tell me what should I look on the Baeldung page.

Comment: Read it all. Learn the framework. Or do not use it. If we use frameworks without understanding them, chances are, we are not using but misusing them.

Comment: Currently I only want to know the answer for my main question. When I used .when().thenReturn() method combination, learned from the previous documentations and that one sent by you, now it works properly. Is it the solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is required to mock your own implementation to every method participating in service we want to test.

For example using BDDMockito:

```java
given(modelMapper.map(dto, Account.class))
    .willReturn(/*some object we want to return*/)
```

It is the only thing we need in our Unit Test, because we only want to check the logic of something we're testing.

For testing every part of our service we must write Integration Test.

Yes, it was fault, and I want to thank [@Turing85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4216641/turing85) for pointing me to the solution of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Autowired for ModelMapper instead of @Mock and see if the problem solves

Comment: Nope, It doesn't solve the problem. The same thing happening as before.